# Which elastic net to use in Python

Tags: regularization, elastic-net

I need to apply the findings of the Zhou, Hastings Paper in Python. Therefore I wanted to use the sklearn elasticnetCV. But is it the same as the elastic net estimate or the naive elastic net estimate? I am asking because it always seems a lot skewed towards the lasso as it doesn't perform grouping (it always sets the l1_ratio to 0.99).

TLDR: Does the elastic net CV compute the same elastic net as in the paper of Zhou/Hastie?